# Can I call any socket functions concurrently even when they are all running in one single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I know that this question has been asked here many times before but they are all focused on `strand`s and that kind of stuff. Let's take a look at it in a more general manner.

First things first -- let's take a look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html):

> Thread Safety
>
> Distinct objects: Safe.
>
> Shared objects: Unsafe.

So it seems for me that none of these functions can be called concurrently with another, even when they all are `run`ning via the same `io_service` object in one **single** thread:

```
// thread 1
sock.async_write(/* ... */); // happens at the same time as async_read from the thread 2

// thread 2
sock.async_read(/* ... */); // happens at the same time as async_write from the thread 1

// thread 3 (the only thread that calls io_service::run function)
while (true)
{
  io_service.run();
}
```

I think so because there's no wording in the correspoding link that says that it's "Safe, if these operations running under implicit or explicit strand".

Am I right?

Comment: @aichao Note that there's no word about **handlers** of these functions in the "Thread Safety" section of the documentation

Comment: @aichao Could you give me a link to this example?

Comment: For 1_61_0 it is in [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html). It is the http server 3 example.

Comment: @aichao Well, I guess it's because they can't have two concurrent `async_read_some` calls in that example due to logical "synchronization" -- they call `async_read_some` right after the previous call handler was called

Comment: Are you referring to connection::handle_read()? Note, however, that the `connection` object needs to be the same across async calls as that object has the socket object (hence the `shared_from_this`). Do you want to move this discussion to chat. They don't like us going back and forth with comments. BTW, I don't know how to start that.

Comment: @aichao "Are you referring to connection::handle_read()?" -- yep. "Note, however, that the connection object needs to be the same across async calls" -- I know. Look at the example again -- there's no way (as far as I can see) when two or more operations on the same `socket` object will be executed simultaneously. "BTW, I don't know how to start that" -- you can't unless SO automatically suggests so after some amount of comments

Comment: I am misunderstanding the question, but could you please elaborate how concurrent function calls occur when there is only a single thread?  Perhaps it may be easier to express ones concerns with some pseudo code?

Comment: @Tanner Sansbury Edited

Answer (score 0):

In the provided example, `thread1` and `thread2` violate the thread safety requirement of socket.  `thread3` is  inconsequential.

---

The thread safety for a type and the running of the `io_service` are orthogonal.  The [Thread and Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#boost_asio.overview.core.threads.thread_safety) documentation notes:

> In general, it is safe to make concurrent use of distinct objects, but unsafe to make concurrent use of a single object. However, types such as `io_service` provide a stronger guarantee that it is safe to use a single object concurrently.

Therefore, for type `T`:

- when the thread safety of distinct objects is unsafe, given two discrete objects `t1` and `t2` that are of type `T`, then `thread1` must not concurrently invoke functions on `t1` while `thread2` is invoking functions on `t2`
- when the thread safety of distinct objects is safe, given two discrete objects `t1` and `t2` that are of type `T`, then it is safe for `thread1` to concurrently invoke functions on `t1` while `thread2` is invoking functions on `t2`
- when the thread safety of shared objects is unsafe, given object `t` of type `T`, then `thread1` must not concurrently invoke functions on `t` while `thread2` is invoking functions on `t`
- when the thread safety of shared  objects is safe, given object `t` of type `T`, then it is safe for `thread1` to concurrently invoke functions on `t` while `thread2` is invoking functions on `t`

Composed operations, such as [`async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html), can have a non-obvious impact on thread safety.  Composed operations are implemented in zero or more calls to the I/O object.  The initiating function may attempt to perform an I/O operation, and any additional *intermediate operations* are initiated within the context of a thread running the `io_service`.  Therefore, given [`ip::tcp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) where the thread safety on shared objects is unsafe:

```
 thread1                              | thread2
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);   | io_service::work work(io_service);
...                                   | io_service.run();
async_read(socket, ...);              | |-- ...
socket.async_write_some(...)          | `-- ... // possible socket.async_receive()
```

The above is unsafe because `thread1` may attempt to invoke `socket.async_write_some()` while an intermediate operation within `thread2` is invoking `socket.async_receive()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually start threads somewhere explicitly using the std::thread constructor? I'm asking to make sure whether you're not confused about what the `async_read` and `async_write` functions actually do.

If you - as per your example - did just this:

```
sock.async_write(write_handler);
sock.async_read(read_handler);
// Notice: no need to put this in a while loop, this is a blocking call.
io_service.run();
```

Then you don't need to care about multi-threading because both handlers shall be executed **inside** the `io_service.run()` function **one after another** sequentially (only the order in which they are executed is undefined).

Now if you had something like this:

```
sock.async_write(write_handler);
sock.async_read(read_handler);
std::thread thread1([&]() { io_service.run(); });
std::thread thread2([&]() { io_service.run(); });
```

That would be still valid, but now you can't tell in which `io_service.run()` function shall your handlers be executed. It would be possible for the two handlers to be invoked **concurrently** (i.e. one could start before the other one finished). In this case it would be wise to consider strands or explicit locking.

Then there is the third case:

```
std::thread thread1([&]() { sock.async_write(write_handler); });
std::thread thread2([&]() { sock.async_read(read_handler); });
io_service.run();
```

I believe this is how @TannerSansbury understood your pseudocode and as he explained in his answer, this approach would be incorrect.

Which of these three is actually most alike with what you've got?